# Allow user to send email Dot net

Tags: c#, .net-core, smtp, mapi

I am working on an application which requires a feature to allow user to send emails . I looked for SMTP but it requires password ( and i guess it should be used for organization level emails with one time configuration) . I also looked for MAPi using this repo but i could not make it work

https://github.com/PandaWood/Simple-MAPI.NET

So is there a way to achieve this , specifically opening default mail application of the user with attachment.
Thanks

Comment: You should be aware of the limitations of using the default email client. Some users may just use webmail, or other incompatible mail-clients. Not all computers are configured for a specific user etc. So the appropriate solution would likely depend on your specific use case. So you might want to describe that use case a bit more.

Comment: To put forward it simply, Allowing different users to send email to each other with/without an attachment . Thats why i am preferring default email client , if not present , i will just throw an exception

Comment: But what is the context? Regular consumers? Corporate users? Send emails to anyone, or just other users of your application? For what purpose? Sending bug-reports? some form of automated process? Why would the user send the email from your app instead of just opening his/her email client directly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what MS states for the Simple MAPI:

> The use of Simple MAPI is discouraged. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.

Simple MAPI is a set of functions and related data structures you can use to add messaging functionality to Windows-based applications written in C, C++, or Visual Basic. You can use pinvoke to call Simple MAPI functions from your application, see [Writing cross platform P/Invoke code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform) for more information.

Also you may consider using the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol or just automating Outlook (if it is installed on the system). That's the most easiest way.

If you deal with Exchange profiles you may also consider using `EWS` or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api). Read more about EWS in the [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) article.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion , one more thing , does MAPi works with Web Application , as i have read somewhere that it is only compatible with Desktop Application ?

Comment: Use the `mailto` protocol for the web.

Comment: Need attachments for most use cases and i dont think mailto supports attachments

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider calling any web service from your web app where you could use EWS or Graph API.